# What is the meaning of "Vidya Vachaspati"?

Tags: title

What is the meaning of "Vidya Vachaspati"? I know it is a title. Who used to get this title in ancient India? What are the qualifications the native needs to have to be entitled as "Vidya Vachaspati"? There are other titles that Hindu scholars used to get, such as "Mahamahopadhyay". How "Vidya Vachaspati" is different from "Mahamahopadhyay"?